# Is there a specific protocol for fixing time-laps/synchronization issues?

Tags: clinical-psychology

Let's take an extreme case as an example. Let's say someone is in a coma for 8 years and then wakes up.

Does anyone know if there is a defined *clinical psychology*/*fucntional psychology* protocol/routine that that person should undergo to start feeling normal again and be able to synchronize with other people?

I assume get a part-time job to get the routine up and running would be a start but what else in relation to other people? Should that person seek out old peers, try to make connection with new peers or what? Is there a formula for dating age when seeking a partner if such a thing occurs?